# Local Notification Date Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, notifications

I'm trying to notify the user on a specific date coming from the database, I'd actually like to notify a day before, but I'll think about it in the future. I have a Timestamp that looks like `1552483247` =`GMT: Wednesday, 13 March 2019 13:20:47
Your time zone: Wednesday, March 13, 2019 at 10:20:47 GMT-03: 00
Relative: In 9 minutes`
It's a past date, but what matters is that I have a Timestamp value and wanted to know how to use it in my code to schedule a notification in the future, I've been missing a solution for a long time. My code is:

```
scheduleNotification() {
this.localNotifications.schedule({
  id: 1,
  title: 'Seu evento " ' + this.nomeevento + ' "acontecerá amanhã',
  text: 'Clique aqui e confira!',
  data: { mydata: 'My hidden message this is' },
  at: new Date(1552483247000)

});
}
```

But he just does not notify. This way it notifies me in 5 seconds but I tried it in different ways and I did not succeed `at: new date () getTime () + 5 * 1000)`

Could someone please help me with this? I'm using Ionic3. Thank you!

Comment: Did you get the notification?

Comment: Which native plugin are you  using for local notifications

Comment: now i receive. I posted my solution. I using cordova-plugin-local-notification from '@ionic-native/local-notifications'.  Its work now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution after much research and testing.
With the following code I can notify you perfectly. I added `.getTime () - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)` to receive the notification the day before the event. My code now looks like:

```
scheduleNotification(produto) {

var date = new Date(produto.notf.seconds * 1000).getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);   //  - 24 hrs antes do dia p/ notificação!

this.localNotifications.schedule({
  id: +(new Date()),
  title: 'Seu evento "' + produto.nome + '" acontecerá amanhã',
  text: 'Clique aqui e confira!',
  data: { mydata: 'My hidden message this is' },
  icon: 'res://icon',
  smallIcon: 'res://icon',
  at: date
});
}
```

being `produto.notf.seconds * 1000` = my code Timestamp(example - 1552483247000) added multiplied by three, returning three more zeros to Timestamp  (000).